# what is considered a good pedal performance in a fighter?

Tags: flight-controls, fighter, control-surfaces, f-16, fa-18

What is considered a good performance in designing the directional control law in a fighter? Is it acceptable to have some roll when using a pedal? For example, is it acceptable to have 40 degrees roll when using a full pedal?

Comment: I think it's more about roll rate (or moment).

Comment: And duration.  40 degrees in a second is excessive, but not after a minute.  And how do you define “good”?  Performance on par with a non-computer controlled aircraft would be my starting point, fine tune it from there based on test pilot feedback.

Comment: Re  "For example, is it acceptable to have 40 degrees roll when using a full pedal?" -- on an aircraft with non-computerized flight controls, if you held full rudder deflection (w/ no counteracting roll control aileron input) you'd expect (to a loose approximation) to see a constant *roll rate*, not a constant bank ("roll") *angle*.  What that roll rate would be, at any given airspeed, would be depend tremendously on the shape of the particular aircraft.  The question could use some improvement to address this issue.

Comment: And as for computerized control laws?  It's hard to see why you would allow (deem acceptable) *any* significant roll rate in response to rudder input.  But again the question is best framed in terms of roll *rate*, not roll/bank *angle*.  Again, the question could use some improvement to address this issue.

Comment: My question is about the computerized control case. I understand from your response that the roll rate is important. So, How much roll rate is considered a good performance if you use full pedal. In other words, how much can it be at most that you describe the control law as a good one? Is there any reference? Is there any rule of thumb?